# How to send data when content type is "x-www-form-urlencoded"?

Tags: flutter

The content type is x-www-form-urlencoded, the image below shows the data I need to send:

[image]

In the case, data must be combined with & and =, how should I do in this case?

```
String body="des=${div}&kr_desc=`{title=${titleKr}&context=${contextKr}}`&en_desc=`{title=${titleEn}&context=${contextEn}}`&jp_desc=`{title=${titleJp}&context=${contextJp}}`&ch_desc=`{title=${titleCh}&context=${contextCh}}`";
  http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    body:body
  );
```

That's the way I thought of it, but of course it didn't work. Help!

Answer (score 0):

First create object with key pair value, then you can pass data with http post method.  post(Uri.parse(URL), body: bodyobject);

```
Future<Map> postdata() async {
        final bodyobject= {"des": val1,"kr_desc":val2,"title":val3};
        final responce = await post(Uri.parse(URL), body: bodyobject);
        return jsonDecode(responce.body);
      }
```